# Blank Wood Duct Caps (for closed off ducts in floor)

Tags: ducts

We had our crawl space forced air furnace with floor ducts (bad idea to put a furnace in a 3-4 foot crawl space) decommissioned and replaced with attic furnace with wall / ceiling ducts.

Now we have unconnected floor ducts with metal registers and magnetic covers. The magnetic stuff is tacky at best.  Been searching for a wood register with no fins or ducts - just blank.  Utterly simple to me.  Like one of those blank switch plates.  Then it could be stained to a close match to the hardwood floor.

Able to find wood vent registers evertywhere but no blank caps.  Did find some links to make my own (make one with vent holes but don't cut the vent holes) but don't have the tools or diy for that is a bit advanced.

Links, ideas or tips would be most appreciated.

Comment: you could put in regular wooden register covers and put in some LED lights ... sort of a night light

Comment: Yes, regular wood register covers and seal the bottom or something like that is a Plan B.  Just feels like too many ducts in the room since they still look active.  Its probably just me.

Comment: you've got holes in the floor: repair them.

Comment: I would buy some wood and make them. Blocking registers is normally a good way to cause damage to the duct work so they may not be widely available.